# How can i display a success pop up message before redirecting a user to the last php page

Tags: php, redirect, alert

I want to have a pop up window appear to let people know that sending their comment was successful. Once they click on the OK button then they get redirected to the last page that they were on. I can get the alert to work if I remove the last line but they just don't work together. Using my code below the alert message is skipped and it goes directly to the referrer line. I have no idea why. I would really appreciate your help. Thanks.

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO comment (Comment, firstname, lastname, Image_path, Approved)
VALUES ('$comment', '$firstname','$lastname','$target_file','2')";  

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
$message = "Thankyou for your comment.";
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";

} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
}

$conn->close();
  header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot output anything before a header() call as it will cause header already sent error.

Made the redirection using a js code.

**Try this:**

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO comment (Comment, firstname, lastname, Image_path, Approved)
VALUES ('$comment', '$firstname','$lastname','$target_file','2')";  

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
$message = "Thankyou for your comment.";
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
    window.location = '".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']."';
    </script>";

} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
}

$conn->close();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the information and also for helping me with the script. I really appreciate it. It worked well.

Comment: Aparently my question was stupid and not helpful. I have a question ban on my account now

Comment: I had the same problem 2 months ago. I had to reach 1k reputation to bring back the question privilege.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, it will redirect to the previous page 3 seconds after the alert goes up (3000ms)

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO comment (Comment, firstname, lastname, Image_path, Approved)
VALUES ('$comment', '$firstname','$lastname','$target_file','2')";  

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
$message = "Thankyou for your comment.";
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
    echo "function goBack() { setTimeout(function(){ window.history.back(); }, 3000);}";

} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
}

$conn->close();
```

Comment: Thanks for the message. Yours did work and I appreciate that. I will probably use your idea the next time that I am looking to do this and need a timed result. The top answer works best for my current project.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback @Edward68 I implemented the timeout function to let the user enough time to read the alert. Glad to help :)